# How to print lowest price brand name in search results

Tags: java

I have all prices in a list and all titles in a list from this two list i want to get lowest price brand name for that which condition i need to use

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code also helps in replying.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be the following, as long as the values are sorted in both arrays. it is recommended to implement two-dimensional arrays.

```
String[] products = {"lenovo", "huawei", "oppo", "hp", "mac", "msi", "asus", "dell"};
int[] price = {4500000, 1700000, 6500000, 1000000, 3000000, 14000000, 183000000, 44000000};

int lowerValue = 0;
int position = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < price.length; i++) {
    if (price[i] < lowerValue) {
        lowerValue = price[i];
        position = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("the cheapest product is: " + products[position] + " with a price of: "+price[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With little code I can't get an exact feel, but finding the lowest cost index would work like so:

```java
List<String> brandNames = /*some initialization*/;
List<Integer> brandCosts = /*some initialization*/;

int cheapestIndex = 0;
// can start from first index because we are already storing index 0 by default
for(int i=1; i<brandCosts.size(); i++)
    if(brandCosts.get(i) < brandCosts.get(cheapestIndex))
        cheapestIndex = i;
System.out.println("Cheapest Brand: " + brandNames.get(cheapestIndex));
```